# Why is it ok to remove variables with low variance from a dataset

Tags: variance, feature-selection

It is a common practice in data analysis to remove features (independent variables) with low variance for dimensionality reduction, with the justification that a feature with low variance cannot explain much of the variance in the response variable (dependent variable).

However, I don't exactly understand this reasoning.
Here is a counter example (in R syntax):

```
 > independent_variable <- c(100000, 100000.01, 100000.02, 100000.03, 100000.04, 100000.05 )
 > dependent_variable  <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
 > cor(independent_variable , dependent_variable)
 [1] 1          #pearsons correlation = 1
 > var(independent_variable )
 [1] 0.00035     
 > var(dependent_variable)
 [1] 3.5        # low variance of independent variable compared to dependent variable
 > var(independent_variable/mean(independent_variable))
 3.499998e-14   # very low variance
 > var(dependent_variable/mean(dependent_variable))
 [1] 0.2857143  # variance of scaled variables with mean=1
```

What I try to demonstrate in this example is a case where the dependent and independent variables have correlation=1 i.e. the independent variable explains 100% of the variance of the dependent variable, and yet, both in the original and in the mean=1 scaled variables, the variance of the independent variable is much lower than the variance of other variables (in this case, the dependent variable) and therefore it would have been removed according to this reasoning.

What do I miss here?

Comment: You miss nothing: such recommendations have no foundation in theory.  The justification you quote (which sounds like a straw man) is incorrect, because the magnitude of the variance of an explanatory variable gives no information--none at all--about what role it might play in a regression or how strongly it might be associated with any other variable.  In many cases I suspect this practice relies on additional suppositions, such as that all variables have been standardized in a preliminary way.  Please check your source(s) to see whether that might be the case.

Comment: Thanks @whuber. Yes I agree with you. This are not specific sources but rather the most common opinion I read when googling this question. It's weird that this approach is so widely common when there is no theoretical ground to it. Anyhow, thanks for your answer. I'll just move on pretending I never heard it (unless someone else responds here with a good justification)